# Changing how a service is configured

Tags: c#, .net, windows, configuration, windows-services

When installing a service, there is a helpful .NET class called `ServiceProcessInstaller`. This class has a property `Account`, which is a `ServiceAccount` enumeration with possible values LocalService, LocalSystem, NetworkService and User.

This is fine at install-time, but does anybody know how I can change this value for an existing service?

I assuming that I need to move away from the actual install-type classes, and have been researching hooking into the advapi32 ChangeServiceConfig method, WMI and ManagementObjects etc.

Indeed I have found code which will actually change the account under which the service runs,

```
ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + myService + "'");
object[] configParams = new object[11];

configParams[6] = userName;
configParams[7] = password;

object result = mo.InvokeMethod("Change", configParams);
```

(which on its own looks a bit like black magic but makes sense when viewed with the ChangeServiceConfig signature)

However when I apply this code to a service which happens to be installed as LocalSystem, it has no effect (although when I interpret `result` the call is reporting success). This doesn't really surprise me since I am only setting a username and password, I am not saying "rather than running as a local service, this service needs to run under a specific user account".

Now, my gut feel is that I am heading along the right lines here. The problem is that none of the parameters in ChangeServiceConfig appear to offer the opportunity to do this.

Any ideas? TIA, Pete

Comment: How do you interpret result? Is it zero? I ran you code and it seems to work fine (change the account the service runs under) here.

Comment: no the result was non-zero. I'm interested that you say the code worked for you..... were you changing a service from running under a local system account to running under user "xyz", or were you merely changing the account from user "abc" to user "xyz"? And what os are you running? Many thanks, Pete

Comment: It was non-zero. It does not mean success. What was it? I changed from local system to a user, as you described. Running Windows 7.

Comment: It returns with code 0x16. According to msdn, ChangeServiceConfig returns non-zero on success and zero on failure. I had assumed that the value being returned from my call will fall into line with the  ChangeServiceConfig return, hence my assertion that the call was successful. But this is a hunch only. I'm running this under xp.

Comment: zespri, I now agree with you that this code is good. My calls were in a dll previously, but I've just put it into a console-app test rig and it works perfectly. So my problem is clearly something to do with the process the dll is being hosted in rather than the code itself. Thanks anyway for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 16 means "[Service marked for deletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901%28VS.85%29.aspx)". Sometimes when you change service parameter, in particular when you delete / re-create a service you need to reboot your PC for operation to complete. While it's still pending, you can't manipulate service and you get error code 16.

Also, it might not be the case, that you problem has something to do with the fact that the call is inside a dll. If you put you code in a test rig dll and call it from a test rig exe (the same way you tested it in a test rig exe) and don't create / delete service in between I think it will work anyway.

The reason it does not working in your application on my opinion has to do with what you did with the service before (and this something most likely is not described in your question).

Comment: Many thanks for that link zespri, and as you say I still have a problem but not quite in the area where I thought. This gives me a new avenue to explore. Cheers, Pete

Comment: You might want to consider accepting one of the answers, because I believe community has helped you as much as it was possible =)

Comment: My apologies zespri, both your answer and smudge's were very helpful. Unfortunately the site will only let me mark one of them as an answer. which do you think I should take?

Comment: Faq says, whichever you find *most* helpful =)

Answer (score 1):

You need Impersonate an thread to run at context of user.
Try this class :
[A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx)
or this one :
[Impersonate User](http://www.brianlow.com/index.php/2007/04/20/impersonate-user/)

Answer (score 0):

Return code is 21: "Invalid Parameter".

I ran into the same issue:  Problem occurs when trying to apply a new user/password to a service which currently has "LocalSystem" with "Allow Service to interact with desktop" enabled.

To resolve, set the "DesktopInteract" flag in the "Change" query

```
var query = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName));      // string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where Name='{0}'", serviceName);

using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(query))
{
    object[] wmiParams = new object[10];

    //WMI update doesn't work if the service's user is currently set to LocalSystem
    //  with Interact with desktop on
    wmiParams[5] = false;
    wmiParams[6] = serviceUserName;
    wmiParams[7] = password;
    //update credentials for the service
    var rtn = service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
```

}